# NSInvalidArgumentException when updating WebView from AppDelegate

Tags: ios, webview, viewcontroller, appdelegate

I had to do an update in my WebView from the Appdelegate.m

I try it like this:

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(loadWebViewWithContent:) withObject:requestObj waitUntilDone:NO];
```

The loadWebViewWithContent Method works great from ViewController.m, but not from the Appdelegate.

I allready wrote this in my Appdelegate.h:

```
-(void)loadWebViewWithContent:(NSURLRequest *)requestObj;
```

Whats wrong? Please help me. I´m still a big Noob in IOS.

Error:

```
-[AppDelegate loadWebViewWithContent]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1f86a5e0*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[AppDelegate loadWebViewWithContent]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1f86a5e0'
```

UPDATE(new try): `UIViewController *view = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    [view performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(loadWebViewWithContent:) withObject:requestObj waitUntilDone:NO];`

Comment: What kind of an error message or compiler error did you get? Additional details are needed

Comment: Sorry i forgot that. :) UPDATED

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are calling method in `AppDelegate` itself. But there is no method in `AppDelegate` called `loadWebViewWithContent:`

if you want to call the method from `AppDelegate` to `ViewController`, you should use, `ViewController` instance to call that method, use like this

`[viewController performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(loadWebViewWithContent:) withObject:requestObj waitUntilDone:NO];`

Comment: Yeah i thinks thats what i want, but XCode say: "Unknown receiver 'viewController'; did you mean 'UIViewController'?

Comment: yeah its your `UIViewController`, don't write `viewController`. I gave that just for example. In your `AppDelegate` somehow u called your `viewcontroller` or you'll instantiated that. Like
`ViewController *view = [[ViewController alloc] init];`
and then call that function like,
`[view performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(loadWebViewWithContent:) withObject:requestObj waitUntilDone:NO];`

Comment: Thanks for helping, but its still the error: "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController loadWebViewWithContent:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1e08abc0'"

Comment: check in your view controller, either you are having `loadWebViewWithContent:` method or not

Comment: Yes i have "-(void)loadWebViewWithContent:(NSURLRequest *)requestObj
{ //load some stuff}" in ViewController.m and "-(void)loadWebViewWithContent:(NSURLRequest *)requestObj;
" in ViewController.h

Comment: can you update your AppDelegate code, i couldn't find anything

Comment: can you show me how you are calling your view controller method, from appdelegate.

Comment: Ok hope it helps to help! :)

Comment: hey dude, don't use `UIViewController`. i meant in your file you'll have one file other than `AppDelegate`, let say if the file name is `ViewController` then try `ViewController *view = [[ViewController alloc] init];` then call `[view performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(loadWebViewWithContent:) withObject:requestObj waitUntilDone:NO];`

Comment: Yes the other file names ViewController.m and ViewController.h! But when i use your code, than xcode say: Unknown type name 'ViewController' did you mean 'UIViewController'? :(

Comment: write this code `#import "ViewController.h"` below `#import "AppDelegate.h"`  in your `AppDelegate.m` file

Comment: Oh yes i forgot the import. But i have still the error: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController loadWebViewWithContent:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1d8dabd0'  and a warning: Incomatible pointer types initializing 'ViewController*__strong' with an expression of type 'UIViewController*'

Comment: `ViewController *view = [[ViewController alloc] init];
[view performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(loadWebViewWithContent:) withObject:requestObj waitUntilDone:NO];`

Comment: Oh i´m so stupid. Thanks allot. No more Error! :) But the method loadWebViewWithContent does not do what to do, but that is another problem.